# jquery won't load the content in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, division

I have been having an issue previewing the website inside IE. For all other browsers the website works just fine but not for the evil one.
I have been been trying for a while to solve the problem but unsuccessful. I think I might run out of ideas. :/ Is there anyone who might point me in the right direction and help me out solve the problem.

The website can be seen on this address: http://www.flyingcowproduction.com/platinumlimoservices

if you click on any of the menu buttons the jquery won't load the content in IE :(

Many, many thanks in advance

Best regards,

-Davorin

Comment: post the non functioning code here please!

Comment: I don't see how it can fully work in _any_ browser.  You have 404 errors on [`scroll.css`](http://www.flyingcowproduction.com/platinumlimoservices/css/scroll.css) as well as some of your fonts and a png.

Comment: I see an error in IE when clicking a menu item at a specific line on a specific script. Can you post the code surrounding this error?

Comment: @Sparky672, the website is still under construction. I am aware of errors reported regarding to javascripts and CSS. I will do the cleanup of the code once the time permits me to do so.

Comment: @DavorinSavovic You can expect the javascript to work with errors. Run it through a debugger. Fix each error and I suspect everything will start working as it does in the other browsers.

Comment: Please don't ask us to help you find errors in your code _before_ you clean it up to remove errors you already know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is breaking on this line:

```
var iframe = $("#jQuery_history")[0].contentWindow.window;
```

jquery.history.js, line 33
Unable to get value of the property 'contentWindow': object is null or undefined

---

It then breaks again if you go to the services page

```
showArea(id[0]);
```

PageNavigation.js, line 296 character 3
'showArea' is undefined

The second one probably just happens because of the first error.

---

**PS - In IE, push F12 and use the script debugger and you can solve this with a little help from google.**

Comment: IE is more restrictive with brackets.  Try using  `$("#jQuery_history").get(0)` instead.